# EditText loses focus on input values

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, galaxy

My application has structure like below-

```
<RelativeLayout>
    ...
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
         ....
         <EditText ... />
         ....
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I am trying to input values in `EditText`, it loses focus and scrolls up to top.

It is focused when I first click it, but loses when I click any values (a-z) of softkeyboard.

Important issue is Application works fine on other devices and has this error only on certain devices (e.g. galaxy S4)

I already made 'adjustpan' and EditText's focusable true.

And there is no focus handling source in .java file.

Anyone has solution to this problem?

or Galaxy S4 has any issue on this problem?

Comment: Paste your xml layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason.

This issue only works on the condition below

1. Galaxy S4
2. using EditText with 'number' inputType
3. using gravity not left 
   (only horizontal gravity makes issue. any vertical gravity works as normal)

So I did like below

1. make empty space (marginBottom) so that keyboard may not block edittext
2. For some Edittext, set gravity to left and calculate device pixel and give edittext marginLeft
   so that edittext works as if it's gravity is right

If anyone has better solution, please tell me how..

Comment: Hi. I've got a similar issue on the galaxy tab 10.1. My edittext is in a ListView... as soon as I enter a character, the window scrolls back up and the keyboard blocks the edittext... haven't been able to solve this one yet

Comment: @Initiator... agreed. Seems Samsung is modifying a lot more of Android than necessary.